# Hover entire container contents with an Overlay

Tags: highcharts

how to display an OVERLAY effect on entire Highcharts graph on mouseover?

something similar to [contentHover](http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/#demo5)

Also to add more display another graph on click of any hyperlink from the contentHover!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's hover method like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3zUGj/

The contents of the overlay div can be whatever you like. The overlay has zero opacity to start. Within the .hover event methods the overlay can be shown and hidden by manipulating the opacity or with other jQuery effects: show, hide, fadeIn, fadeOut, etc.

html

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="contentHover" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; background:#999; text-align:center; padding:20px;top:0px; position:absolute; z-index:100; opacity:0"><a href="">New Graph</a></div>
```

js

```js
// high chart
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        … highcharts implementation …
    });
});

// show hide the contentHover div on hover
var hover = $('#contentHover');
$('#contentHover').hover( function(){
    hover.css('opacity','1');
}, function(){
    hover.css('opacity','0');
});

// add click event to all links within contentHover, add new chart
$('#contentHover').on('click','a',function(){
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        … highcharts implementation …
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add mouseover / mouse out action to chart conainer div.

ie.

```
$('#container').mouseover(function(event){
```

$('#overlay').show();

}).mouseout(function(event){

$('#overlay').hide();

});

Where overlay is id of div (position absolute) which is "over" than chart.